# Core Data: keypath name not found in entity

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm crashing with this message :

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath name not found in entity

Obvisouly I'm not querying my entity correctly .

```
//fetching Data

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Viewer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSString *attributeName = @"dF";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",attributeName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"predicate : %@",predicate);
NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"items : %@",items);

[fetchRequest release];
    
//end of fetch
```

And here is my data Model:

[image]

I want to return the value of "dF", shouldn't call it like this ? :

```
NSString *attributeName = @"dF";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",attributeName];
```

Comment: What is `name` on your predicate? There is no property `name` on your entity!

Comment: ah, that's where I`m getting confused then . I want to return the value of the Attribute whose name is "dF" .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get value from your `dF` property, you have to fetch an array of `NSManagedObjects` and then use `[fetchedManagedObject valueForKey:@"dF"];` to get your value.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Viewer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];

NSManagedObject *mo = [items objectAtIndex:0];  // assuming that array is not empty
id value = [mo valueForKey:@"dF"];
```

Predicates are used to get array of `NSManagedObjects` that satisfy your criteria. E.g. if your `dF` is a number, you can create predicate like "`dF > 100`", then your fetch request will return an array with `NSManagedObjects` that will have dF values that > 100. But if you want to get just values, you don't need any predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a NSSortDescriptor initialized with a String `key`:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<SomeManagedObject>(entityName: "SomeManagedObject")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

I then changed the name of the `name` attribute in the model. Refactored all of the property names, but didn't catch the stringly typed `key: "name"`.

The solution for Swift is to use `NSSortDescriptor(keyPath:` instead, which will fail to compile if the property key path changes.

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SomeManagedObject.firstName, ascending: true)
```